# Photo gallery using different sized images in fixed viewable area

Tags: slideshow, thumbnails, sprite, photo-gallery, fixed-width

I'm hoping you can help and I'm hoping this isn't a duplicate (I've already been searching for the past 2 hours trying to find a solution).

### What I'm currently doing:

I am using the Pikachoose Photo Gallery - http://www.pikachoose.com but I am open to others. I just need a very basic photo gallery that I can populate from a database. I have gotten the photo gallery looking 95% of how I need it to look but I'm running into a big problem. Although the width is set, the height is not as this would cause skewing of the image. I would assume most of the images will be landscape. So what happens while the slider rotates through the images, the main larger viewable area changes height based on the image that is loaded. It would be fine if all images were the same height/width, but that's not a possibility as I will not have control over the images loaded.
They are loaded into an unordered list and when clicked, will open a page that has the full image.

[image]

### What I need it to do:

I'm familiar with how sprites work, but I wanted to know if there was a way to incorporate that type of functionality into the slider (i.e. Flickr does for thumbnails). I want to have a fixed height/width viewable area, such as 220px x 150px, and have the image load into that making the longest side 220 + 40 pixels (in case it's a narrow image) and center it, but you still only see 220px x 150px. Same with the thumbnails, I want them to be set width/height 50x50 pixels, which they are right now, but the images are squished. If I can solve either the main image or the thumbnail, I think I can solve it for the other. But I don't even know where to start.

See below for a visual example. **Note: I meant for the thumbnails to read "set shortest side to 50px" not longest...**

[image]